# Drupal entity metadata wrapper no bundle property

Tags: entities

Using `<?php
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid);
?>`

When I `$wrapper->title->value();` I get error msg that property Title does not exist....

Using Entity 7.x 1-8 and D7.56. I am aware that `$nid` can be a node (from node_load) or a node id.

What am I missing?

Comment: I was just fiddling around with a test Drupal 7. The only way I could reproduce an error was by giving a non-existent `$nid` value. Are you sure the node in question exists?

Comment: The issue you linked is (in my opinion because I faced it last year) resolvable by increasing your opcache memory consumption value and your opcache memory value - in regards to the "missing token information". Basically if this is related, you don't have enough cache to store it all.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it applying this patch:
https://www.drupal.org/project/entity/issues/2819665

although I to be honest don't understand why...